# Filter a dropdown list

Tags: c#, winforms, filtering

I have a dropdown list bound to a list of objects. The list can have over 20000 items. I do not want to populate the list immediately. However, when the user types in the text portion of the list, the control should start filtering the list and display matching items.

I was trying the following:

```
    private void cboName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query1 = allNames.Where(x => x.firstname.Contains(cboName.Text) || x.lastname.Contains(cboName.Text)).ToList();

        cboName.DataSource = query1;
        cboName.ValueMember = "id";
        cboName.DisplayMember = "firstname";
    }
```

But it doesn't work performance-wise.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the data source a Database?

Comment: No. A list<T> that I populate from a JSON file.

Comment: You can add an eventlistener that will fetch the data using the value the user typed in the text portion. After the filtering you can bind the fetched data to that dropdownlist.     edit: after seeing what you did you can maybe increase performance by only taking the first 20 results?

Comment: 20000 items in a list to choose from? I would try to rethink this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you can try out this

[TextBox.AutoCompleteMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the list to use as the custom source.  
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(new string[]
                    {
                        "January",
                        "February",
                        "March",
                        "April",
                        "May",
                        "June",
                        "July",
                        "August",
                        "September",
                        "October",
                        "November",
                        "December"
                    });

    // Create and initialize the text box. 
    var textBox = new TextBox
                  {
                      AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                      //Appends both Suggest and Append options.
                      AutoCompleteMode = 
                          AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                      AutoCompleteSource =
                          AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                      Location = new Point(20, 20),
                      Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                      Visible = true
                  };

    // Add the text box to the form.
    Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Comment: This suggestion works nearly perfect. Only issue is that the matching is done from the beginning of the strings and not from anywhere within the strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with your code that you already have.

```
private void cboName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query1 = allNames.Where(x => x.firstname.Contains(cboName.Text) || x.lastname.Contains(cboName.Text)).ToList();

        cboName.DataSource = query1;
        cboName.ValueMember = "id";
        cboName.DisplayMember = "firstname";
    }
```

You can set a delay, before you filter, or use the `keydown` with a listen to the `enter` Key and than filter the list.